# Populate a dropdown list from php and .dat

Tags: php, html, xml

I've tried searching about this here on SO and also through Google, but the options mentioned haven't worked so far. I won't say that the codes are not written correctly, it might just be the way I've done the setup, that is the mistake. But I've tried different types of solutions for solving the case, but so far it's still not working.

Just a quick information heads-up, I'm a first year IT student and we haven't started with MySQL yet.

This is how my index looks like so far:

```
    window.onload = oppstart;

var xmlhttp;

function oppstart() {
  document.getElementById("registrer").onclick = lagre;
}

function lagre(){
  var nedtrekksliste = document.getElementById("nedtrekksliste").value;
  var navn = document.getElementById("navn").value;
  var epost = document.getElementById("epost").value;

  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = statusforandring;

  var url = "registrer.php?nedtrekksliste=" + nedtrekksliste + "&navn=" + navn + "&epost=" + epost;

  xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
  xmlhttp.send();

  function statusforandring(){

    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
      document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = "Du har nå registert påmelding til en av våre presentasjoner. Takk og ha en fin dag videre hilsen Enigma!";
    }
  }
}
```

This is how I wrote up my PHP:

```
  $nedtrekksliste = $_GET["nedtrekksliste"];
  $navn = $_GET["navn"];
  $epost = $_GET["epost"];

  $linje = $nedtrekksListe . "¤" . $navn . "¤" . $ePost . "¤" . "\n";

  $fil = fopen("data.dat", "a");
  fwrite = ($fil, $linje);
  fclose ($fil);

  echo "Du har nå registrert emnevalg, takk!";
```

Finally, this is the data content I'm trying to populate inn to the dropdown list, while my wanted information is in a .dat file format:

```
812¤SuperIT¤2016-12-06 18:00¤25¤
135¤OddIT¤2016-01-10 17:25¤10¤
614¤MediaHuset¤2016-12-14 16:15¤67¤
1337¤Elite¤2017-02-22 15:45¤31¤
135¤ParIT¤2016-03-17 18:30¤7¤
147¤L2P¤2017-01-10 20:00¤5¤
```

The task I got is to create a registration form for selecting one of the options for which presentation a student would like to attend. I already have fixed the register button and 2x input text area which are meant for the student to write their name and e-mail. So I can't seem to solve the dropdown list problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading a file in php is quite simple, if your index is a mix of html and php, you can read data.dat and build the SELECT from inside the HTML as such:

**Index.php**

```
<select name="presentations">

        <?php

            // path to your file ( in this case, both files within same dir)
            $filename = "data.dat";

            // open the file in read only monde
            $file = fopen( $filename, "r" );

            // get the file size, read and store the content in '$fileText'
            $filesize = filesize( $filename );
            $filetext = fread( $file, $filesize );

            // seperate the content of the data file into an array of lines
            $lines = explode("\n", $filetext);

            // loop through every line  
            for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($lines); $i++) {

                // seperate this line according to the seperator '¤'
                $members = explode("¤", $lines[$i]);

                // we can now access the individual members of this line
                $id = $members[0];
                $name = $members[1];
                $datetime = $members[2];
                $room = $members[3];

                // outputs a 'Option' element inside the SELECT of our HTML page
                echo '<option value="'. $id . '">' . $name . '</option>';
            }

        ?>

</select>
```

If your index is just HTML, you can build a JSON object in PHP, and then (in a similar way as above) build the SELECT with javascript.

Then, you need to complete your javascript to get the selected presentation:

**functions.js**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // SELECT element on HTML page
    var selected = document.getElementById("presentations");

    // storing the ID of the selected field
    var ID_presentation = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].value;
    // OR
    // storing the name
    var ID_presentation = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text;
</script>
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for all the support! I solved the dropdown list issue with the first alternative. I also found out that the way I wrote the code for how to let the user write to a new .dat file.